# Separate JSON elements into columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to separate elements from a list into different columns of a pandas dataframe. Essentially I want, for every `tenure` option - i.e. Detached, Semi-detached, columns like `detached_price`, `detached_cost`, `detached_rooms` and `detached_asking`, then the same for Semi-detached, Terraced, Flats etc.

```
p = [{'br8': [{'tenure': 'Detached',
    'data': ['£1,248,554', '£571', '4.3', '£1,063,001']},
   {'tenure': 'Semi-detached',
    'data': ['£581,968', '£499', '3.3', '£587,188']},
   {'tenure': 'Terraced', 'data': ['£520,725', '£516', '3.0', '£474,719']},
   {'tenure': 'Flats', 'data': ['£424,898', '£516', '2.0', '£394,092']}]}]
```

I've tried this so far, but it won't parse the columns correctly. Does anybody have any advice or direction as to how to achieve my goal here?

`pd.DataFrame.from_records(p).T`

My desired output is:

```
     detached_price, detached_cost, detached_rooms, detached_asking, semi_detached_price, etc etc
br8  £1,248,554,    £571 ,          4.3 ,            £1,063,001,     £581,968
```

Comment: Did the solution work on your real data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be quite a long dataframe, but the below should work :

first we import some modules, and assign your columns, I'm assuming you have a full set of data and no NA values. if you do, you'll need to figure out a way to map your ask, cost, room into your dataframe.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import cycle
import pandas as pd


dfs  = defaultdict(list)

for index,y in p[0].items():
    for _ in y:
        for key, value in _.items():
            dfs[key].append(value)
            dfs['index'] = index

df = pd.DataFrame(dfs).set_index('index')

df = df.explode('data')

status = cycle( ['price','cost','room','ask'])

df['status'] = [next(status) for stat in range(len(df))]

df['tenure'] = df['tenure'] + '_' + df['status']

final = pd.crosstab(df.index,df.tenure,values=df.data,aggfunc='first')

print(final.iloc[:,:4])
```

---

```
tenure    Detached_ask Detached_cost Detached_price Detached_room
postcode?                                                        
br8         £1,063,001          £571     £1,248,554           4.3
```